# How to make Nuxt-auth and Nuxt-i18n to be friends

Tags: javascript, authentication, vue.js, internationalization, nuxt.js

I want to use nuxt@auth module and nuxt-i18n together. The problem appears when I want to have different routes for login page. For example:

```
pages: {
 login: {
  en: '/authorization',
  fr: '/autorisation'
 }
}
```

Routes are working well, but when I try to use nuxt@auth with all page restricted, the default redirect asks for /login page. In nuxt.config.js file I can rewrite redirect route, but I can set only one redirect.

```
auth: {
 redirect: {
  login: '/fr/autorisation'
 }
}
```

How can I show to auth module to ask for route of selected language? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 31, accepted):

Hope it'll be helpful for somebody =)

```
export default ({ app, $auth }) => {
 $auth.onRedirect((to, from) => {
   return app.localePath(to)
  })
}
```

Comment: This is the correct solution. It respects prefix_except_default (no prefix for default language) and works flawlessly with single page behaviour (switch language -> login)

Comment: Is this as plugin or middleware?

Comment: @Rozkalns it's the plugin

Comment: Works perfectly!
Just wanted to clear that the plugin must be registered in auth config, not with the plugins property, https://auth.nuxtjs.org/recipes/extend

Comment: This totally rocks! Thanks!

Answer (score 9):

It seems that there was a solution for that problem https://github.com/nuxt-community/auth-module/pull/185, but I can't access to `onRedirect` method in the current release.

I did a workaround. I added `auth-lang-redirect.js` plugin, which overrides `redirect` option defined in the `nuxt.config.js` file.

```
export default ({ app }) => {
  var redirect = app.$auth.$storage.options.redirect
  for (var key in redirect) {
    redirect[key] = '/' + app.i18n.locale + redirect[key]
  }
  app.$auth.$storage.options.redirect = redirect
}
```

Notice that I don't use `nuxt-i18n` module, but you should get the point. 
You have to register this plugin in `nuxt.config.js` like this:

```
auth: {
    strategies: { ... },
    redirect: {
      login: '/login',
      logout: '/',
      callback: '/login',
      home: '/user/profile'
    },
    plugins: ['@/plugins/auth-lang-redirect.js']
  },
```

Comment: Thanks, I allready fixed that problem, my workaround it's without for, but does the same thing.

Answer (score 2):

```
export default function({ app, $auth }) {
  const redirect = { ...$auth.$storage.options.redirect };

  const localizeRedirects = () => {
    for (const key in redirect) {
      $auth.$storage.options.redirect[key] = app.localePath(redirect[key]);
    }
  };

  localizeRedirects();

  app.i18n.onLanguageSwitched = () => {
    localizeRedirects();
  };
}
```